# WordPress Term for Custom List

Tags: terms

Would you mind helping me out. I am experienced in programming yet really new to wordpress. I was task to handle this. I just need to know what are these called (The ones with the pin icon): [Image is here](http://s21.postimg.org/xqaxp9fl3/wordpress.png) (I can't seem to post images here without 10+ reputation, sorry)

In SharePoint this could have been Custom list, im just not sure what it is called in wordpress. I need to know its name to search for it. Also, how can I add a new "list", export and import contents in built. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress they are called Custom Post Types. You can create them for instance in the functions.php. There are many examples in the web how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

These are custom post types.

You create them by registering them with WordPress on page loads. You do this by calling register_post_type either in:

- Your themes `functions.php`
- On the `init` hook ( I may be mistaken here but it should work )
- In a small plugin ( ***Highly Recommended method, good for data portability*** )

You call register_post_type like this:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'Books' );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

[Read more about `register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

[You can also use this handy generator to create the code for you after giving it some information like a name and description](http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/)

You may also be interested in reading about custom taxonomies ( categories and tags are taxonomies )